# Problems importing gluon.html from outside web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I want to try to code some gluon-derived components (`web2py` html helpers), outside from `web2py`. This way I can test components on the command line, and generate simple html files which I can analize before integrating them with the complete `web2py` application stack. This speeds up my development cycle, since I can concentrate on finetuning the HTML of the component without worrying about any other issues (redeploys, databases, ...). Fast and easy: prepare a web2py component with `gluon.html` helpers, see if the HTML generated looks good, and *then* use it from within `web2py`.

The test has been mostly successful. I just had to:

```
from   gluon.html                import A, TABLE, DIV, SPAN, THEAD, TR, TH, TBODY, URL, H1

def T(txt):
    return txt

def my_simple_component(title):
    return H1(T(title))

def test():
    print my_simple_component('Hello')
```

Which produces the expected output:

```
$ python test_web2py_components.py
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

(I do not care about `T` in my tests. And for my any test `URL` that I want to use, I just pass a fake application / controller / function.)

The only problem that I have found is that I need to have a symbolic link to `web2py` for the `gluon.html` import to work, even though gluon is on the PYTHONPATH.

```
ln -s /install_dir/web2py/gluon/ .
```

**Is there a way to import gluon components without having that extra link?**

Consider that during the test phase my components are outside of the web2py application tree.

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib_test1.py", line 4, in <module>
    from   gluon.html                import A, TABLE, DIV, SPAN, THEAD, TR, TH, TBODY, URL
  File "/install_dir/web2py/gluon/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from globals import current
  File "/install_dir/web2py/gluon/globals.py", line 24, in <module>
    from serializers import json, custom_json
  File "/install_dir/web2py/gluon/serializers.py", line 11, in <module>
    from languages import lazyT
  File "/install_dir/web2py/gluon/languages.py", line 264, in <module>
    PLURAL_RULES = read_possible_plurals()
  File "/install_dir/web2py/gluon/languages.py", line 250, in read_possible_plurals
    for pname in os.listdir(pdir):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/current_dir/gluon/contrib/rules'
```

(Do not consider `install_dir` and `current_dir`: they have been introduced for this question)

Answer (score 2):

You should not have to make the link.

If you want the import to find "gluon", the folder that should be at PYTHONPATH is its parent: sys.path.insert(0,'/install_dir/web2py').

This works, (here the zip contains the gluon folder):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\web2py\library.zip')
>>> from gluon.html import H1
>>> print H1("Hello")
<h1>Hello</h1>
```